# missing FROM-clause entry for table postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables: `mks_equipment` and `mks_equipment_packs`.

`mks_equipment` has: `ID`, `TypeName`, `Brnand`
`mks_equipment_packs` has: `packID`, `RockShoes`, `Helmet`.
Both `RockShoes` and `Helmet` are referencing to `mks_eqipment.ID`.

I want to make a Trigger, that will raise an exception if you are trying to add `ID`, refering to non-helmet item into `Helmet` column in `mks_equipment_packs`.

Here's the code of trigger:

```
IF (NEW.packid < 0 ) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'It can not be a negative number!';     END IF;
IF((mks_equipment.type != 'RockShoes' ) AND (mks_equipment.ID = NEW.rockshoes)) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong piece of equipment!';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
```

And here'sthe problem. If I try to `INSERT INTO mks_equipment_packs VALUES (31, 33, 84)`,

Then It says:

```
Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "mks_equipment"
LINE 1: SELECT (mks_equipment.type != 'RockShoes') AND (mks_equipmen...
                ^
QUERY:  SELECT (mks_equipment.type != 'RockShoes') AND (mks_equipment.ID = NEW.rockshoes)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function mks_equipment_checks() line 5 at IF
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

P.S. The tsak specifically says: I can not split my mks_equipment table in several tables. It is just prohibited.

Comment: why not using FK?..

Comment: Foreign keys, ok. I see. I used them like this:
`CREATE TABLE mks_equipment_packs ( 
packID integer PRIMARY KEY, 
Helmet REFERENCES mks_equipment (ID),
RockShoes REFERENCES mks_equipmet (ID)
)`
And the tsak specifically says: I can not split my mks_equipment table in several tables. It is just prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

`mks_equipment.type` is a column of a table, which makes no sense in that context. You have to specify which of the many rows in the table you mean.

You are probably looking for a construct like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM mks_equipment
           WHERE type <> 'Rock Shoes'
             AND id = NEW.rockshoes)
THEN ...
```